# Emacs Meta-Key in Terminal

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to configure my Meta-Key, such that I can input {},[], etc. in a terminal emacs  (using a German keyboard). I haved tried setting my Meta-Key, but can't get it to work. I want to use Alt+8 for {, Alt+9 for }, Alt-5 for [, Alt-6 for ].

```
(setq mac-option-modifier nil
      mac-command-modifier 'meta
      x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

See:
[Unable to type braces and square braces in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376863/unable-to-type-braces-and-square-braces-in-emacs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-8") "{")
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-9") "}")
```

Comment: Additional info: I had to add this to ~/.emacs.d/init.el (Mac)

Answer (score 0):

For macos azerty French keyboard. It's :

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-(") "{")
(define-key global-map (kbd "M-)") "}")
```