# Emacs on Mac - how to enter brackets, pipes, @, etc?

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm quite new to Emacs on my Mac and I have trouble entering signs like: []|{}@ etc. Instead the minibuffer shows `M-5`, `M-6` or jumps a word forward (`M-l`).

I think I got my Emacs here: http://emacsformacosx.com/
and I did install this starter kit: http://kieranhealy.org/emacs-starter-kit.html
(but I hat this problem before)

I know this answer: [Unable to type braces and square braces in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376863/unable-to-type-braces-and-square-braces-in-emacs)
but I couldn't get it to work yet.

Comment: This question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895950/emacs-meta-key-in-terminal

Answer (score 0):

I use the following -- it will place the Emacs meta key on the Mac CMD key, and free up the ALT key for normal Mac use:

```
(if (boundp 'ns-command-modifier)
    (setq ns-command-modifier 'meta))

(if (boundp 'ns-option-modifier)
    (setq ns-option-modifier nil))
```

Comment: I put in my init.el and restarted, but but **Alt+7** still produces `M-7`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure they took effect (for example, if your init file wasn't read, or it contained an error prior to these lines). Try checking the values with `C-h v`.